# Difference between Serverless Containers and other containers

Tags: docker, containers, serverless-architecture, serverless

I've read about people switching over from Docker to Serverless but what scratches my head is, are there any performance difference? I mean, both are containers, so there shouldn't be any difference at all?

Let's say you create a single function that returns a certain calculated number, and you deploy this as Serverless and to docker. My guess is that both should perform that function equally fast, am I wrong?

My understanding is that Serverless containers are just like Docker except they're "smaller" and only runs when function is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker-based applications and serverless applications both use containers so there is conceptually no difference between the two at runtime.

The only difference is that with Docker-based applications you have to manage the container/image yourself but in serverless, you don't need to.

You can fully customize your container with Docker-based applications but with serverless, you can only choose from the available runtimes.